# Using BigInteger Multiply operator

Tags: java, biginteger

I was wondering if there was a way to multiply `BigInteger` variables together, because the `*` operator cannot be applied to `BigInteger`.

So I was wondering if it was possible to multiply two `BigIntegers` together without using the `*` operator.

Comment: Operators only work on objects if it can go through [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). The only ones that can do that are the class representations for the primitive types (int -> Integer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You use [`BigInteger`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) `multiply()` method like so:

```
BigInteger int1 = new BigInteger("131224324234234234234313");
BigInteger int2 = new BigInteger("13345663456346435648234313");
BigInteger result =  int1.multiply(int2)
```

I should have pointed out a while ago that `BigInteger` is immutable. So any result of an operation has to be stored into a variable. The operator or operand are never changed.

Comment: If this gets too annoying, you can do work in Groovy which maps the operators correctly.  I am implementing some math classes (BigRational for one) and for the first time Java has seemed extremely cumbersome--Although I generally love Java I have to admit that it's not the answer to every programming problem.  If you need Java's speed but want advantages like Operator Overloading you might also try Scala.

Comment: In the last snippet line, isn't just "int2" is sufficient as argument passed to multiply? It's a BigInteger after all.

Comment: @amar Thanks for pointing that out. I'm not sure what I was thinking. Probably a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 5):

Easier way to implement:

```
int i = 5;
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("12345678901");
BigInteger result = bigInt.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multiply(BigInteger) method in BigInteger. So:

```
BigInteger result = someBigInt.multiply(anotherBigInt);
```

[BigInteger in Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 0):

The result multiplying these specific factors

A: 131224324234234234234313

B: 13345663456346435648234313

Could be this one (I hope I am correct):

R: 1751275668516575787795211751170772134115968581969

Both are considered being two positive integers. And the technique used
was Karatsuba’s method

int ab = (mul1) * 10^n + (mul3 - mul1 - mul2) * 10^n/2 + mul2;

Comment: This does not address the question.